# C - How to resolve memory leaks?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, jansson

Below is the part of script and the same is invoked from main function. If i comment out the below function, everything works fine without any memory leak issue, whereas by including this function, the process ends up with memory leak and eventually it stops over a span of 2 hrs.

```
void passRFIDInfo(int antenna_id, int peakRssi, char *fast_id, int reader_mac_flag, int data_accumulated_flag){

  if (reader_mac_flag == 0){
    struct ifreq s;

      int fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);


    strcpy(s.ifr_name, "eth0");
    if (0 == ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &s)) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
      unsigned char data  =  s.ifr_addr.sa_data[i];
      sprintf(reader_mac+(i*2), "%02x", data);
    }
    reader_mac[12] = '\0';
    }
  }

  char uniqueID[40];



  char *antennaID = (char*)malloc(2);
  snprintf(antennaID, sizeof(antennaID), "%d", antenna_id);


  strcpy(uniqueID, reader_mac);

  strcat(uniqueID, ".");
  strcat(uniqueID, antennaID);
  strcat(uniqueID, ".");
  strcat(uniqueID, fast_id);



  int json_size = json_object_size(root);

  if (data_accumulated_flag==1 && json_size!=0) 
  {

    sendMQTT(rfid_json_dict);

    free(rfid_json_dict);      
    json_decref(root);

    json_t *root = json_object();  
    char *rfid_json_dict;
  }

  json_object_set_new( root, uniqueID, json_integer(peakRssi));
  rfid_json_dict = json_dumps(root, 0);

  printf("rfid_json_dict ::%s\n",rfid_json_dict);
  printf("\n");

}
```

Before the program executes, the available memory in an embedded linux platform is,

```
>show system cpu
Status='0,Success'
TotalMemory='62304256'
FreeMemory='18621122'
CPUUtilization='3'
```

As the execution continues for 2 hrs and so, the FreeMemory keeps going down and eventually at the end of 3 hrs, the process killed automatically. How to resolve such kind of issue?

Comment: `char *antennaID = (char*)malloc(2);` allocates 2 bytes but you never `free` it. It's not much, but after 2 hours that will mount up.

Comment: It's quite strange code though: `char *rfid_json_dict;` was defined *after* you first use it. How does it compile? Is `rfid_json_dict` "shadowing" a global variable of the same name?

Comment: Also fun: `char *antennaID = (char*)malloc(2);
  snprintf(antennaID, sizeof(antennaID), "%d", antenna_id);` spot the error(s).

Comment: @EOF  I supposed it's a single digit value, but the 7 lines which build `uniqueID` can be replaced with a single `snprintf` anyway.

Comment: @WeatherVane No cookie for you. It's the `sizeof(pointer)`.

Comment: @EOF uh-oh the cookie crumbled.

Answer (score 0):

Just as it was pointed out in the comments, you're missing a call to `free()` on `antennaID`. So you `malloc()` memory for it, but then it's never freed. So it just keeps piling up.

The general rule is that for every call to `malloc()`, there should be a call to `free()`. At least, that's how I learned, and that's what makes the most sense to me. As soon as you're done using a variable, you should `free()` it. Briefly going through that code, it doesn't look like `antennaID` ever *leaves* the function? So you should be good to just free it before the function returns.